# Is there a way to limit results in VMWare vcenter api

Tags: api, vmware, vcenter

I'm using vcenter API from VMWare, and I was wondering if there's a parameter to control the result limit?

```
**
vmware_inv=`curl -X GET -k -H "vmware-use-header-authn: string"  \
            -H "vmware-api-session-id: $vmware_token" "https://$vmware_endpoint/rest/vcenter/vm"`
**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to limit the response beyond what's already offered by default (which is generally responses of 1,000)